# Corrupted malloc area by scanf()

Tags: c, malloc

i have an issue with my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
typedef struct hashTable{
char *data;
struct hashTable *next;
}HASHTABLE;

HASHTABLE **linkedHashTable[100];
void SaveHashTable1(char *str2,char *str3)          //s retazenim---Linked List
{
int hashResult;
HASHTABLE* linkedHashTableNode=NULL, *new_;

hashResult=StringToInt(str2);

if(linkedHashTable[hashResult]==NULL)
{
    linkedHashTableNode=(HASHTABLE*)malloc(sizeof(HASHTABLE));

    linkedHashTableNode->data=(char*)malloc(strlen(str3)*sizeof(char));
    strcpy(linkedHashTableNode->data,str3);

    linkedHashTableNode->next=NULL;
    linkedHashTable[hashResult]=&linkedHashTableNode;
}
else
{
    linkedHashTableNode=*linkedHashTable[hashResult];
    while(linkedHashTableNode->next!=NULL)
        linkedHashTableNode=linkedHashTableNode->next;

    new_=(HASHTABLE*)malloc(sizeof(HASHTABLE));

    new_->data=(char*)malloc(strlen(str3)*sizeof(char));
    strcpy(new_->data,str3);
    new_->next=NULL;
    linkedHashTableNode->next=new_;
}

 }
 int main(void)
 {
char *str1=NULL, *str2=NULL, *str3=NULL;
int i;


while(1)
{
    scanf("%s ", str1);
    if((strcmp(str1, "save"))==0)       //SAVE
    {
        scanf("%s %[^\n]s", str2, str3);

        SaveHashTable1(str2, str3);
    }
}
}
```

this is part of code, wich I have problem, when I try execute this:

```
linkedHashTableNode->data=(char*)malloc(strlen(str3)*sizeof(char));
strcpy(linkedHashTableNode->data,str3);
```

always I get memmory space near by memory area of scanf(), so when I read data from console again,  then original data  are rewrite. And I have no Idea where can be a problem.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You're not requesting enough memory in the `malloc` call. `strlen` tells you how many characters are in the string, *not including the terminating NUL*, but `strcpy` is going to copy the terminating NUL character anyway.

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me that you have a couple of problems.

First of all, the scanf() function can be a bit dicey to use so you may want to consider modifying the main so that you get a line at a time using gets() and then parse the line of input.  However this is not a show stopper.

In your main() you need to allocate memory for str1, str2, and str3.  They are pointers to NULL in your question.  See [scanf man page](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/scanf/).

I suggest you take a look at the following, modified version of your application.  Still using the scanf() however there are several other changes that you should consider.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
typedef struct hashTable{
    char  *data;
    struct hashTable *next;
}HASHTABLE;

HASHTABLE *linkedHashTable[100];

// stub version of StringToInt() so that it will compile and I can
// do a couple of simple tests in the debugger.
int StringToInt(char *str2)
{
    return 1;
}

void SaveHashTable1(char *str2,char *str3)          //s retazenim---Linked List
{
    int hashResult;
    HASHTABLE *new_;

    hashResult=StringToInt(str2);

    new_ = (HASHTABLE *)malloc(sizeof(HASHTABLE));
    if(linkedHashTable[hashResult] != NULL)
    {
        // since there is at least one entry in the table, lets traverse the list
        // until we reach the end.  we will then append our new entry onto the end.
        HASHTABLE *linkedHashTableNode;
        HASHTABLE *lastLinkedHashTableNode;

        linkedHashTableNode = linkedHashTable[hashResult];
        while(linkedHashTableNode != NULL) {
            lastLinkedHashTableNode = linkedHashTableNode;
            linkedHashTableNode = linkedHashTableNode->next;
        }
        lastLinkedHashTableNode->next = new_;
    } else {
        linkedHashTable[hashResult] = new_;
    }

    new_->data = (char *)malloc(strlen(str3) + 1);
    strcpy(new_->data, str3);
    new_->next=NULL;
}

int main(void)
{
    char  str1[128], str2[128], str3[128];

    while(1)
    {
        scanf("%s ", str1);
        if((strcmp(str1, "save"))==0)       //SAVE
        {
            scanf("%s %[^\n]s", str2, str3);
            SaveHashTable1(str2, str3);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @user1726810, if this answers your question, please mark it as an answer.  You had several problems with your code that this rewrite addresses.  You need to understand that a local, stack variable will disappear after a function returns so keeping the address of it as you were in your hash table will not work.  All in all you had a number of problems involving memory and variables so that is an area you should do further study.

Answer (score 0):

you should notice that `strlen("hello world") == 11` but "hello world needs a `char[12]` to be stored

`strlen(str3)` returns the number of char in `str3` but doesn't count the `'\0'` car at the end of `strlen3`

therefore strcpy is not able to copy the end string caractere